# What does "droppin' me notes" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He(Hagrid) seemed numb with shock at the verdict.
>
> "S'all my fault. Got all tongue-tied. They was all sittin' there in black robes an' I kep' **droppin' me notes** and forgettin' all them dates yeh looked up fer me, Hermione. An' then Lucius Malfoy stood up an' said his bit, and the Committee jus' did exac'ly what he told 'em...."

Does "droppin' me notes" take its literal meaning here? (E.g. Hagrid kept dropping his notes on the ground.) I've looked it up, but it doesn't seem to be a normal collocation. Does it have a special meaning in this context?

Comment: I know of no special meaning for it. When I read it, I interpret it literally.

Comment: It is not a collocation at all.  You can drop virtually anything that you can hold in your hand--car keys,  wallet, notebook, sunglasses, toothbrush, pencil.  Is it the word **me** (for "my") that is throwing you off the simple literal meaning here?

Comment: Aside from Hagrid's transliterated English West Country accent, the sentence is literal:  "The absent-minded professor was always **dropping his notes** during his lectures, and so frequently wandered off topic."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So, what's "notes" referring to? It could be the paper we make notes on or the information itself according to dictionaries. Does "drop my notes" here mean "keep going off the topic" or "literally dropping the paper they make notes on"?

Comment: **notes** are sheets of paper or small cards with writing on them.  The things written down are also called "notes", just as we can say "I'm going to tear  up these crappy **instructions** and toss them in the trashcan" when we're trying to put some prefab furniture together.  The word **instructions** refers to the paper and its contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning is literal, but you have to forgive Hagrid for his non-standard grammar and West Country accent.

In something like standard, RP English:

*It is* all my fault. *I* got all tongue-tied. They *were* all sittin*g* there in black robes, an*d* I kep*t dropping my notes* and forgettin*g* all *those* dates *that you* looked up *for* me, Hermione.

Hagrid is defending Buckbeak in a sort of court of law. Hermione had written some notes for Hagrid to use. But Hagrid is rather clumsy and dropped the papers on which these notes were written on the floor, making him look foolish in front of the judges. Also because he dropped the notes, he can't find the information that was written on them, so he couldn't argue his case.

Answer (score 2):

It's literal.

Hagrid had a number of points he wanted to address in front of the committee, so he wrote them down in his notes. When it actually came time to use those notes, he kept dropping them, probably because he was nervous and upset. Imagine someone struggling to get their point across, then dropping their notes, then spending thirty seconds getting their notes off the floor. Repeat this several times. The end result was he did a bad job with his presentation.

It's really not unusual for people to have [notecards](https://www.staples.com/Staples-3-x-5-Line-Ruled-White-Index-Cards-500-Pack-23634-40801/product_233601) with notes on them when they're doing public speaking. In the public speaking class I took, we were advised to number our cards so that they could not get out of order. With the exception of two or three people who memorized their speech, everyone in my class used notecards.